# Node spits out this random error, I cant see the problem in my code

Tags: javascript, node.js, backend

I am working on a esp32 wifi speaker, I got the board going, and now I need to make a server from where you can stream what songs you'd like. I'm new to working on the backend and i'm having trouble with this error: `node:internal/errors:465 ErrorCaptureStackTrace(err);`
Here is my code:

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const ytdl = require("ytdl-core");
const express = require("express");
var cors = require("cors");
var path = require("path");
const app = express();
var http = require("http").createServer(app);
const io = require("socket.io")(http);
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

const port = process.env.PORT || 8080;
const adress = '127.0.0.1';

var clientGlob = null;
var destDir = "./Music";

var songs = [];
var songDur = [];

var playing = false;
var curSong = '';

app.use(express.json()); // to support JSON-encoded bodies
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true })); // to support URL-encoded bodies
app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true })); 

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname,"index.html"));
});

app.post("/downAudio", (req, res) => {
    getAudio(req.body.url, res);
 });

getAudio = (videoURL, res) => {
    console.log(videoURL);
    var stream = ytdl(videoURL, {
      quality: "highestaudio",
      filter: "audioonly",
    })
  
    var videoReadableStream = ytdl(videoURL, { filter: 'audioonly'});

    ytdl.getInfo(videoURL).then((info) => {
      console.log("title:", info.videoDetails.title);
      console.log("rating:", info.player_response.videoDetails.averageRating);
      console.log("uploaded by:", info.videoDetails.author.name);
      
      var videoName = info.videoDetails.title.replace('|','').toString('ascii');

      var videoWritableStream = fs.createWriteStream(destDir + '\\' + videoName + '.mp3'); 

      var stream = videoReadableStream.pipe(videoWritableStream);
      
      stream.on('finish', function() {
        res.writeHead(204);
        res.end();
      });     

      console.log("File downloaded and added to the queue");
      songs.push(destDir + '\\' + videoName + '.mp3');
      
      var duration = parseInt(info.videoDetails.lengthSeconds);
      songDur.push(duration*1000);
      console.log("Audio added to the queue")
      if(!playing)
        play();
    });

};

play = ()=>{
  playing=true;
  curSong=songs[0];
  setTimeout(playNext(),songDur[0]);
}

playNext = ()=>
{
  fs.unlink(curSong, function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
    console.log('File deleted!');
  });
  songs.pop()
  songDur.pop();
  if(songs.length!=0)
    play();
  else
    playing=false;
}


io.on("connection", (client) => {
    clientGlob = client;
    console.log("User connected");
});

app.listen(port,adress, () => {
   console.log(`Server started, link: ${adress}:${port}`);
});
```

It downloads the songs fine but it has a problem in the playnext function. I cant relate this error to anything in there. What am I doing wrong?
Also any help into improving the code and performance is welcome.
If needed I will provide more information, thanks!

Comment: Please log the entire output error.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the problem, for some reason it didn't like the type of function I used. After making it a normal function `playnext(){}...` it worked.